# Calculate total columns in winforms gridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Inside form there is gridview which is populated with following columns

```
CODE, NAME, PRICE, QNT, TOTAL
1     Test  4.00    1   4.00
2     Test2 3.50    2   7.00
```

How can I calculate this total column to be in this case 11.00 and for example add that value to the labelOverall.Text property?

Thanks

Update

Gridview is populated like this

```
var sel = (Article)cmbArticleList.SelectedItem;

            DataRow newRow = articlesTable.NewRow();
            newRow["CODE"] = sel.Code;
            newRow["Name"] = sel.Name;

            articlesTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
            articlesGridView.DataSource = articlesTable;
```

Comment: how you get the total in `TOTAL` column??will you please share it..

Answer (score 2):

In general you should always use the `DataSource` to calculate sums, preferably in the database itself. 
However, if you want to calculate it afterwards at the client, you should prefer the datasource of the grid anyway instead of parsing the cell text or other approaches that use the grid.

For example in the `DataBound` event which is triggered directly after all rows were databound:

```
protected void GridDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView grid = (GridView)sender;
    DataTable source = (DataTable)grid.DataSource;
    decimal totalSum = source.AsEnumerable().Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("Total"));
    labelOverall.Text = totalSum.ToString();
}
```

Note that the `Field` method is strongly-typed and throws an exception if it's actual type is different.

Answer (score 1):

The DataTable has a [Compute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) method that allows you to perform calculations on the table data.

So to calculate the sum of the Total row you can do the following:

```
var sum = articlesTable.Compute("SUM(TOTAL)", "");
newRow["Total"] = sum;
```

This should calculate the sum and then update the Total row.

Remember to do this before adding the row to the table. :-)

EDIT:
The second argument of the Compute method is a filter expression. This allows you to filter which rows are included in the calculation in case you need that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your code:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0; i<gv.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   sum += gv[i, 4].Value;
}
```

Comment: Why convert to string and then back to int?

Comment: @RuneGrimstad yeah you are right, but i remains always doubtful about datatype used by user to store values in database, thats why i usually do the stuff like this. But i will prefer to remove it now.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
labelOverall.Text  = articlesGridView.Rows.Cells.Select(n => Convert.ToDouble(n["TOTAL"].Value)).Aggregate((a,b) => a + b).ToInvariantString();
```

This will select and convert all the *total cells*, sum them and assign the answer to `labelOverall.Text`.

Comment: Why convert to string and then back to int?

Comment: You mean to int and back to string?

Comment: Yep. The total column will probably be a number

Comment: It's a dataGridView which means its definitely a Text, the computation has to be done using int values, and then the result converted back to text and assigned to the label text property.

Comment: The data source is a DataTable object, so the source values will probably not be text

Comment: I disagree. First, there is a big performance cost when converting to and from string, second you should convert to double since the nubmers are decimal numbers :) and third the conversion may fail depending on system locales. If for instance the numbers are displayed using "." as the decimal separator while the system locale expects ",".

Comment: Yeah, it should be `Convert.ToDouble` but there's no performance loss in converting from `int to int`. Neither is it inappropriate to convert the answer to string, so I don't really get what you're saying there.

Comment: Hmm, I just noticed that I misread your code. I read it as Convert.ToInt32(n["Total"].ToString()) ... so a ToString followed by a ToInt32. So this was my fault, your code is perfect :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do it as

```
int sum;
sum = articlesTable.Compute("Sum(COLUMNNAME)", "COLUMNNAME<> 0");
```

Now the `sum` get the total of that coulmn